# Replace column values using regex in pandas data frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in `pandas` data frame like below. Column name is `ABC`

```
ABC
Fuel
FUEL
Fuel_12_ab
Fuel_1
Lube
Lube_1
Lube_12_a
cat_Lube
```

Now I want to replace the values in this column using regex like below

```
ABC
Fuel
FUEL
Fuel
Fuel
Lube
Lube
Lube
cat_Lube
```

How can we do this type of string matching in `pandas` data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind for `lube` or `fuel` while ignoring case.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

pat = re.compile('(?<=lube|fuel)_', re.IGNORECASE)

df.assign(ABC=[re.split(pat, x, 1)[0] for x in df.ABC])

        ABC
0      Fuel
1      FUEL
2      Fuel
3      Fuel
4      Lube
5      Lube
6      Lube
7  cat_Lube
```

Comment: `_\d` uses 19 steps instead of 51 steps

Comment: @ctwheels so is this even better?: `re.compile('(?<=lube|fuel)_.*', re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: Ya stick with the one you've just commented, OP added new input in a comment below [MaxU's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47024464/3600709) which causes the other answers to break on `\d` use.

Answer (score 8):

```
In [63]: df.ABC.str.replace(r'_\d+.*', r'')
Out[63]:
0        Fuel
1        FUEL
2        Fuel
3        Fuel
4        Lube
5        Lube
6        Lube
7    cat_Lube
Name: ABC, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.ABC.str.split('_\d', 1).str[0]`

Comment: @MaxU Good trick just a small doubt if my column has `Fuel_aa_12` will this work.

Comment: @piRSquared, please add it as an answer! :)

Comment: I added a different one.

Comment: This is the replace version  `df.ABC.str.replace('(?<=lube|fuel).*', '', case=False)`  Oddly enough, I can't pass an ignore case flag to `pd.Series.str.split`.

Comment: @piRSquared, thank you! But i think OP might have more than `(lube|fuel)` values. I'm not sure though... :-)

Comment: The `[]` is not necessary, `[\d]+` should be `\d`

Comment: @MaxU `Fuel` is the desired output for `Fuel_aa_12`

Comment: @New_learner you should add more possible inputs to your question if that's the case. 2/3 answers here break due to the new input you've just described.

Answer (score 5):

Alt with `str.extract`:

```
df.ABC.str.extract('^(.*?)(?=_\d|$)', expand=False)

0        Fuel
1        FUEL
2        Fuel
3        Fuel
4        Lube
5        Lube
6        Lube
7    cat_Lube
Name: ABC, dtype: object
```

---

Extension courtesy piRSquared:

```
df.ABC.str.extract('(.*(?<=lube|fuel)).*', re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)

0        Fuel
1        FUEL
2        Fuel
3        Fuel
4        Lube
5        Lube
6        Lube
7    cat_Lube
Name: ABC, dtype: object
```

Comment: `pd.Series.str.extract` version `df.ABC.str.extract('(.*(?<=lube|fuel)).*', re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)`

Comment: Adding `^` at the beginning of the query halves the number of steps (180 instead of 363)

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks, that's interesting to know (added).